# How to get small dataframes based on values of an attribute?

Tags: r, loops

`x` is a `data.frame`

```
id  income  age 
1   23246  21
1   12455  45
3   24555  31
2   10045  42
```

I would like to have 3 data frames based on id number

Answer (score 1):

`split(x,x$id)` will produce a list of data frames split on id.

Comment: I am sorry, it looks trivial, but I want to save the results of corresponding values for each id in a data frame. Like a loop or sth does it to get the result
x1 <- 23246  21
        12455  45
x2<- 10045  42,
x3<- 24555  31

Comment: @Y.esk It is advisable to store the splitted `data.frame`s in a `list` (rather than as "loose" objects in your environment). The `split` command generates a `list`, which then can be conveniently processed/manipulated using functions from the `*apply` family.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is `list2env`, i.e.,

```
xs <- split(x,x$id)
list2env(setNames(xs,paste0("df",names(xs))),
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

which creates data frames `df1`, `df2` and `df3` in your global environment, such that

```
> df1
  id income age
1  1  23246  21
2  1  12455  45
> df2
  id income age
4  2  10045  42
> df3
  id income age
3  3  24555  31
```

Comment: No, this is not good R coding practice! Instead of having loose objects floating around in your global environment it is much better/safer to store the objects in a `list`. It will also make accessing/manipulating the sub-`data.frame`s much more straightforward using `lapply`/`sapply` etc.

Comment: @MauritsEvers then `xs <- split(x, x$id)` would be enough

Comment: Yes, see the first answer by @GeorgeSavva.